# Java environment variable is not available until I format the namenode

Tags: hadoop, failed-installation

[JAVA ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzDpZ.png)[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9hHc.png)
Hadoop namenode cannot be formatted. Guys, when I was installing hadoop I got a error when I type command hadoop namenode format. I'm posting you screenshot of my please. Please help me set export path of `JAVA_HOME` .

Answer (score 0):

set the following environmental variables in bashrc or bash_profile:

> export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin/:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/
>
> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_51
>
> export HADOOP_HOME=/home/vasanth/Desktop/software/hadoop-2.7.1

Try the following things before formatting name nodes again:

1.check weather `jvm` is there in folder `/usr/lib`.

2.execute the environmental variables in the file using `source ~/.bash_profile` command from terminal.

3.check weather there is another `jvm` folder anywhere in your machine(different version of java).